# Hp stream 11 ubuntu 14.04 wifi not working

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I have looked everywhere for a solution none worked HP stream 11= no hard drive only 32 gb motherboard so I previously have windows 8.1 on it I installed pro all the wifi was working no Ethernet and then I decided since I am a root developer for Android I know c++ and java in used to sublime and cmd and terminal I released a root for htc desire 626s with no exploits needed = htcdesire626srootbyturnerhackz1.weebly.com but where getting off topic I tanned USB installer Ubuntu iso rebooted pressed esc tanned Ubuntu live on USB Wi-Fi was just amazing actually better than windows but once installed rebooted then I realized the Wi-Fi wasn't working and each time I try to enable the driver through software and update it goes halfway and stop then revert so I did in terminal sudo lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 =BROADCOM COPERATION BCM43142 802.11B/G/N SUBSYSTEN HEWLETT-PACKARD COMPANY DEVICE KERNEL DRIVER IN USR BCMA-PCI-BRIDE PLEASE HELP IM EXPECTED TO RELEASE A ROOT WITHING 3 WEEKS AND IVE BEEN STRUGGLING TO INSTALL UBUNTU FOR TWO WEEKS NOW PLEASE HELP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured it out myself download the latest linux generic header and image and also download the latest bcmwl and dkms .deb files onto USB and then copy to Ubuntu desktop and then open terminal the 4 debs still on the desktop then type cd ~/Desktop 
Then type sudo su 
Then type dpkg -i *.deb 
Walla close everything then open system settings then click software and updates the  click additional drivers it should say using broadcom 802.11 Linux sta wireless driver it should say you need to restart the computer to complete the driver changes boom lick restart then your finished everything should be fine put this post as solved